# Problem in draw rect

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I use below code in viewLoad (i don't want to draw in `- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect`)for add rect on view but doesn't work.why?

```
CGRect rect=CGRectMake(10,10,150,140);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGFloat red[4] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
CGContextSetStrokeColor(context, red);
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, 10, 10);
CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
CGContextStrokePath(context);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` will return nil when there is no current context. A context is created for you before `drawRect:` is called; if you want to create a context manually, use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` or `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to start one, `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()` to extract the UIImage, and `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` when you're done with it to release the context. See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html) for details.

You could also, of course, create a [CGBitmapContextRef](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGBitmapContext/Reference/reference.html) and use CoreGraphics calls directly rather than UIKit calls. There are pros and cons to each approach, the major difference being the default transformation matrix.

Answer (score 6):

You can only draw when you've got a drawing context. You can either create an image context anywhere you like to create an image, or you can draw inside `drawRect:` to draw to your view. You are not supposed to draw to your view outside of `drawRect:`.

It might look like you're getting a context, but in fact you don't as [`UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` returns `nil` outside of `drawRect:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext) (or to be more correct: it only returns a context inside `drawRect:` or if you've created and pushed an image context yourself).

Comment: My previous comment was stupid, did not read the question well enough. +1 for correct answer.